# XML XDocument - There appears to be no elements

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to understand XDocument and it's various methods.

I have a site map, and I'm trying to read the URLs

```
<urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
         <loc>http://www.site.co.uk/</loc>
    </url>
    <url>
         <loc>http://www.site.co.uk/page</loc>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

The above parses fine and I'm trying to read the values of loc (the page URLs) but this where it goes wrong

```
        string siteMapText = String.Empty();
        GetValueOfPageFromWebClient(SiteMapUrl, out siteMapText);

        XDocument siteMap =
            XDocument.Parse(siteMapText);

        foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants())
        {
            //logic
        }
```

In my C#

```
loc.Element("loc").Value //should show value but doesn't
```

How do I iterate over the `loc` values?

**EDIT**

As per Jon Skeet's answer, I tried

If I do

```
  foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants("loc"))
  {
      //never enters
  }
```

The same is true with

```
  foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants("url"))
  {
      //never enters
  }
```

I've had to do
      foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants())
      {
           if (loc.Name.LocalName != "url")
                continue;
           //code
      }

Can some one explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I iterate over the loc values?

The simplest way is to use the overload of `Descendants` which accepts an `XName`:

```
foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants("loc"))
{
    string value = loc.Value;
    ...
}
```

Currently, you're asking for the `loc` element within each element - but neither the root element nor the `loc` elements contain `loc` child elements, so `Element` returns `null`, leading to an exception.

Now it seems that the XML isn't *actually* as you've shown it to be in the question. Instead, it has a default namespace:

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" ...>
```

So all the descendant elements are in that namespace too, because they don't specify anything else... so you need to specify the namespace when you're looking for things. Fortunately, that's easy:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9";
foreach (var loc in siteMap.Descendants(ns + "loc"))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Actually, I'm sorry to say, it doesn't work! When I over load `Descendants("loc")`, the foreach jumps straight over (indicating it has no children). Even if I update to `siteMap.Descendants("url")` the same issue persists

Comment: Strange, that works for me. However I get an error when I parse the XML you gave in the question. For your issue, it might be a namespace issue, have a look at the XML that is in siteMapText.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: That suggests the XML isn't as you've shown it to be - e.g. it's got a namespace that you haven't shown. That would explain everything, and it's easy to fix by using the namespace. If you could make the XML in the question reflect the *actual* XML you're using, I'm sure we can fix it easily.

Comment: @JonSkeet, to my knowledge, it is (just a shorter version)... http://www.001ltd.co.uk/sitemap.xml

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: No, you missed out the `xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"` part in your sample XML. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions: Edited - but this really shows the importance of giving short but *complete* examples in questions.